# [line 35 unexpected EOF while looking for matching ' " ' and line 40 unexpected end of file]

Tags: linux, syntax

This is my homework to write calculator on shell script but there is two errors and I couldn't find the solutions.

```
echo "---------Welcome to Simple Calculator--------"
echo "p=PLUS"
echo "m=MINUS"
echo "x=MULTIPLICATION"
echo "d=DIVISION"
read -p "Enter your choice" ch
if $ch -eq p
then
    echo "Enter Two Number For PLUS"
    read x
    read y
    echo "Sonuç:  $((x+y))"
elif $ch -eq m
then
    echo "Enter Two Number For MINUS"
    read x
    read y
    echo "Sonuç: $((x-y))
elif $ch -eq x
then
    echo "Enter Two Number For  MULTIPLICATION"
    read x
    read y
    echo "Sonuç: $((x\*y))"
elif $ch -eq d
then
    echo "Enter Two Number For DIVISION"
    read x
    read y
    echo "scale=2;x/y" | bc
else
    echo "Stopping calculator"
fi
```

Comment: The second "Sonuç: $((x*y)) is missing the closing parentheses.

Comment: Nope. It is missing a double quote, but the parenthesis are fine

Comment: Generally it's helpful to include the error messages you get, or to provide a worked example that triggers the errors.

Answer (score 3):

Using a shell syntax checker such as https://www.shellcheck.net/ will help you identify the more obvious syntax errors, such as missing quotes.

However, it won't help with your `if ... then` clauses, all of which are missing a test operator. Here's an example:

```
if $ch -eq p
```

This will fail with some sort of "Command not found" error when you try to run it. (This is why it's helpful to include the output from running a program in the question.)

What you probably meant was this, which uses the test operator `[[`..`]]` to perform a string comparison rather than a numeric one.

```
if [[ "$ch" == p ]]
```

Finally, it's good practice to double-quote all your variables everywhere you use them, i.e. `"$ch"` instead of `$ch`.

Comment: Additionally `-eq` performs an equality test on two _integers_... It would be better to us a `case` statement here.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. Case statement? Yes agreed but I assumed the OP hadn't got that far through Scripting 101 yet.

Answer (score 2):

In the subtraction section you are missing a `"` (double quote):

```
echo "Sonuç: $((x-y))
```